# So I found this in the hot questions list, with a math font. Is that a bug?

Tags: bug, hot-questions

[image]

The second questions from Board Games appears to be using math fonts in the hot questions. Even weirder, when going to the question, [the question title appears normal.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32485/should-i-get-200-for-passing-go-if-i-then-get-a-card-that-says-dont-collect) The html of the div is below.

```
<li>
            <div class="favicon favicon-boardgames" title="Board &amp; Card Games Stack Exchange"></div><a href="https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32485/should-i-get-200-for-passing-go-if-i-then-get-a-card-that-says-dont-collect" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ item_type:11, target_site:147 }); posts_hot_network.click({ item_type:2, location:11 })">
                Should I get <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mn>200</mn><mi>f</mi><mi>o</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>p</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>i</mi><mi>n</mi><mi>g</mi><mo>&amp;quot;</mo><mi>G</mi><mi>o</mi><mo>&amp;quot;</mo><mi>i</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>I</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>h</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>n</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>h</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>y</mi><mi>s</mi><mo>&amp;quot;</mo><mi>d</mi><mi>o</mi><msup><mi>n</mi><mo>&amp;#x2032;</mo></msup><mi>t</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>o</mi><mi>l</mi><mi>l</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>t</mi></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-1" role="math" style="width: 21.462em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 17.851em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.128em 1017.78em 5.837em -999.997em); top: -4.024em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 17.851em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.128em 1008.68em 4.448em -999.997em); top: -4.024em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-3" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">200</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-4" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.073em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-5" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">o</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-6" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">r</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-7" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">p</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-8" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">a</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-9" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">s</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-10" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">s</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-11" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">i</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-12" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">n</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-13" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">g<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-14" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.281em;">"</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-15" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic; padding-left: 0.281em;">G</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-16" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">o</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.031em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.059em 1017.78em 4.448em -999.997em); top: -2.635em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-17" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">"</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-18" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic; padding-left: 0.281em;">i</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-19" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.073em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-20" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">I<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.073em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-21" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-22" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">h</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-23" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">e</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-24" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">n</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-25" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">g<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-26" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">e</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-27" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-28" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">a</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-29" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">c</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-30" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">a</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-31" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">r</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-32" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">d<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-33" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-34" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">h</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-35" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">a</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-36" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-37" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">s</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-38" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">a</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-39" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">y<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-40" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">s</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-41" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.281em;">"</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-42" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic; padding-left: 0.281em;">d<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-43" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">o</span><span class="msup" id="MathJax-Span-44"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0.906em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.406em 1000.56em 4.24em -999.997em); top: -4.024em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-45" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">n</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.031em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -4.372em; left: 0.628em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-46" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">′</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.031em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-47" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-48" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">c</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-49" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">o</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-50" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">l</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-51" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">l</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-52" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">e</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-53" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">c</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-54" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">t</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.031em;"></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.031em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.996em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 2.921em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>200</mn><mi>f</mi><mi>o</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>p</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>i</mi><mi>n</mi><mi>g</mi><mo>"</mo><mi>G</mi><mi>o</mi><mo>"</mo><mi>i</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>I</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>h</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>n</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>r</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>h</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>t</mi><mi>s</mi><mi>a</mi><mi>y</mi><mi>s</mi><mo>"</mo><mi>d</mi><mi>o</mi><msup><mi>n</mi><mo>′</mo></msup><mi>t</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>o</mi><mi>l</mi><mi>l</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>c</mi><mi>t</mi></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1">200 for passing "Go" if I then get a card that says "don't collect </script>200"?
            </a>

        </li>
```